# Can't receive information from contact form using php, js, ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have a contact form on a website, information from contact form I want to receive to email with all the fields that was filled by user, but I can't. What's wrong with the code. Maybe there are some other way that I can do it. Please, help to fix it!

HTML "contact.php":

```
 <html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name = "viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>CloudK</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/bootstrap-337.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awsome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/contactsyle.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/stylesss.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>


<body>
  <div class="cus-padding">
    <div class="bg-area"></div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <div class="contact-form">
            <h2>Связаться с Нами</h2>
            <form  action="" id="mailForm">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" placeholder="Имя">
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" value="" placeholder="Фамилия">
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <input type="tel" name="phone" id="phone" value="" placeholder="Номер Телефона">
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="" placeholder="Электроная почта">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <input type="text" name="company" id="company" value="" placeholder="Название компании">
                </div>
              </div>

              <p><textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea></p>
              <p><input type="submit" id="sendMail" value="Отправить"></input></p>

            </form>

            <div id="errorMess">

            </div>
```

The following is JS "formMail.js":

```
$("#sendMail").on("click", function(){
  var  name = $("#name").val().trim();
  var  lastname = $("#lastname").val().trim();
  var  email = $("#email").val().trim();
  var  phone = $("#phone").val().trim();
  var  company = $("#company").val().trim();
  var  message = $("#message").val().trim();

  if (name == ""){
    $("#errorMess").text("Введите Ваше Имя!");
    return false;
  }else if (lastname == ""){
    $("#errorMess").text("Введите Вашу Фамилию!");
    return false;
  }else if (email == ""){
    $("#errorMess").text("Введите Вашу Электроную почу!");
    return false;
  }else if (phone == ""){
    $("#errorMess").text("Введите Ваш номер телефона!");
    return false;
  }else if (company == ""){
    $("#errorMess").text("Введите название компании!");
    return false;
  }

  $("#errorMess").text("");

  $.ajax({

    url: 'ajax/mail.php',
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    data: {'name':name, 'lastname':lastname, 'email':email, 'phone':phone, 'company':company, 'message':message},
    dataType: 'html',
    beforeSend: function(){
      $("#sendMail").prop("disabled", true);
    },
    success: function(data){
      if(!data)
        alert("Были ошибки, заявка не отправлена!");
      else
        $("#mailForm").trigger("reset");

      $("#sendMail").prop("disabled", false);

    }

  });

});
```

and the php "mail.php":

```
<?php

  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $lasname = $_POST['lasname'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $phone = $_POST['phone'];
  $company = $_POST['company'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];


  $subject = "=?utf-8?B?".base64_encode("Сообщение с Сайта")."?=";
  $headers = "From: $email\r\nReply-to: $email\r\nContent-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";

  $success = mail("emil10azizov@gmail.com", $subject, $message, $headers);
  echo $success;


 ?>;
```

Comment: What do you mean *you can't*? Where does it go wrong?

Comment: I don't receive anything. First I was receiving just  $message = $_POST['message']; (message field) without name, last name, phone, now I don't receive anything.

Comment: So start by narrowing it down... Use the debug console of your browser, does the data get posted? You're in a much better position to debug this than us.

Comment: @ficuscr can't figure out! that's why posted it.

Comment: Well only you can tell us what we need to know. Can you tell us if the JavaScript for the #sendMail click event handler fires? And if so, does the Xhr request it generates include the values you want to POST? Do you know how to check those two things?

Comment: @ficuscr I don't really know how to check these, i am just learning, new to it.

Comment: No problem. Let's take it step by step. Quick test if handler is firing. Add `console.log('I am here');` to the top of you click handler function. Then, open the web browser's **debug console** and check for the output "I am here".

Comment: @ficuscr Ok, I figured out the problem. First I had typo in php, instead of lastname I had lasname. Then I added in $message = '' html with .POST_$ that I needed.

Answer (score -1):

$lastname = $_POST['lastname']; instead of $lasname = $_POST['lasname']; (typo with t)

```
$message = '<html>
               <head>
                     <title>Call me back</title>
                 </head>
             <body>
                 <p><b>Name:</b> '.$_POST['name'].'</p>
                 <p><b>LastName:</b> '.$_POST['lastname'].'</p>
                 <p><b>Phone:</b> '.$_POST['phone'].'</p>
                 <p><b>Company:</b> '.$_POST['company'].'</p>
                 <p><b>Company:</b> '.$_POST['message'].'</p>
             </body>
         </html>';

$subject = "=?utf-8?B?".base64_encode("Сообщение с Сайта")."?=";
  $headers = "From: $email\r\nReply-to: $email\r\nContent-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";

  $success = mail("emil10azizov@gmail.com", $subject, $message, $headers);
  echo $success;
```